# Basic MongoDB Query in C# Application

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am having troubles with a basic mongo db database query in my c# application.

It looks like the Method collection.find(query); is not working.

My Visual Studio only knows "FindAllAs()" or "FindAs()"

When i try the Method FindAllAs().toList() my application can complie, but i get an empty list, allthough my database contains alot of entries.

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;

 public class User
    {
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }        
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }

    }

MongoClient client = new MongoClient(url);
MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
MongoDatabase database = server.GetDatabase("users");
MongoCollection  collection = database.GetCollection<User>("users");

List<User> userList = collection.Find().ToList();
```

Find() ist not a valid Method here, VS cant compile it and suggests FindAllAs();

I am using DB driver 2.8.1

Any clues here?

Thank you!

Comment: Just to verify: Your Database _and_ Collection are named "users"?

Comment: Have you tried `collection.FindAllAs(typeof(User)).ToList();`?

Comment: The **FIRST** thing you should try is run a raw query (pass it by string). `db.findOne()` . If it works, connection to db is done properly and you can start debugging by there

Comment: connection to Database should work, i can create collections from my app using db.CreateCollection("name"); and from the shell i can see that it has been created. i think its an issue with getting the collections from the db - when i try to insert something with db.collection.insert(); my collection remains empty as seen in shell.

Answer (score 0):

ok it seems like i had an issue with the API, i was using an osbolete method here.

client.GetServer() is not used anymore,

you connect to your DB right away with client.GetDatabase();

i could Insert into the collection now properly and also find items.

case closed!